# Keeping a nested structure in a result table while writing over nested data

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to do some brief masking of data in our bigquery table. I need the resulting table to have the same structure, but removed of personal information.

I'm doing something along the lines of:

```
select
customer,
"1234 Road" as tttt.address
...
from table
```

I can't delve into more detail, but I need to overwrite things such as customer name and phone number, while the structure remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
#standardSQL
select
  * EXCEPT(tttt),
  (SELECT AS STRUCT tttt.* REPLACE("1234 Road" AS address)) AS tttt
from table;
```

As a concrete example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH T AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS x,
    'foo' AS y,
    STRUCT('kksdf' AS address, 1234 AS street) AS tttt
)
select
  * EXCEPT(tttt),
  (SELECT AS STRUCT tttt.* REPLACE("1234 Road" AS address)) AS tttt
from T;
```

You can read more about this syntax in the [`Query Syntax` topic](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach to have ability to query live original table with obfuscated/dummy data points

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION dummy_string(value STRING)
AS ((SELECT CONCAT(value, '_', CAST(CAST(100000* RAND() AS INT64) AS STRING))));
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 'customer1' AS customer, 'address1' AS address, 'phone1' AS phone UNION ALL
  SELECT 'customer2' AS customer, 'address2' AS address, 'phone2' AS phone UNION ALL
  SELECT 'customer3' AS customer, 'address3' AS address, 'phone3' AS phone UNION ALL
  SELECT 'customer4' AS customer, 'address4' AS address, 'phone4' AS phone UNION ALL
  SELECT 'customer5' AS customer, 'address5' AS address, 'phone5' AS phone 
)
SELECT * REPLACE(
  dummy_string('aaaa') AS address, 
  dummy_string('bbbb') AS phone
  )
FROM yourTable
```

You can use whatever obfuscation logic you want to have implementing it in dummy_string() [SQL UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions)

Even more - based on this query - you can make a view that will reside in separate dataset (different from dataset where original table is) so whoever will get access to this view (but not to original table) will be able to explore table but with hidden/dummy data-points of your choice

Follow below steps to make it happen

1 - Create a view in a dataset different from dataset where `yourTable` resides. This is important!

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(
  CONCAT('aaaa', '_', cast(CAST(100000* RAND() as INT64) as string)) AS address, 
  CONCAT('bbbb', '_', cast(CAST(100000* RAND() as INT64) as string)) AS phone
  )
FROM yourTable
```

As you can see here - i am not using SQL UDF because UDF are not supported in View (yet - I hope)

2 - Go to Share Dataset Menu of dataset where original table is and add just created view as Authorized View

3 - Go to Share Dataset Menu of dataset where view is created and add as a Viewer those users who you want be able to play with obfuscated original table

Above setup - makes user being able to see and use view - but they will not have access to original table/data

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM yourView
```

I think this example can help you